# How to host a subdomain with a different web host and add to Cloudflare?

Tags: subdomain, cpanel, cloudflare

I have a website `example.extension` hosted with a US web hosting company.

The domain is registered with GoDaddy, and uses name servers from the US web hosting company.

I wish to have a sub-domain `this.example.extension` hosted with an Australian web hosting company.

I know I can add an A record for `this.example.extension` in `example.extension`'s cPanel.

However, I also wish to use Cloudflare for `this.example.extension`, and this requires creating a CNAME record, and CNAME records cannot coexist with A records for the same domain or subdomain. i.e. I cannot have an A record for `this.example.extension` and a CNAME record for `this.example.extension` (according to cPanel).

At the moment, there is simply a CNAME record pointing `this.example.extension` to `this.example.extension.cdn.cloudflare.net`

I've added the site to Cloud Flare, and Cloud Flare knows where the website is created.

Is this enough to ensure the site loads fine?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. configure your site at the Australian web hosting. Make sure the site is configured as this.example.extension. You'll have the IP where the site is located. Yes, you won't be able to see the site, but it's OK for now.
2. at Cloudflare configure this.example.extension.cdn.cloudflare.net to that IP
3. profit! :)

The caveat is the Australian hosting may trouble you because this.example.extension doesn't point to their server. Two ways to deal with this: 1. say 'i know, do it anyway' 2. choose another hosting.

btw, it's better to transfer dns to CloudFlare, if possible. their dns-es are faster than your, and geo-distributed.